# How to tell if avocado has large pit?

Tags: avocados

Is there any way to tell from the outside if an avocado hides a disproportionately large pit and less meat?  It's always a disappointment when you cut one in half just to find out it is mostly pit.

Comment: I would guess that on average, larger avocados have a better meat to pit ratio.  But apparently that guess is wrong: http://marcsala.blogspot.ca/2010/10/does-edible-percentage-of-avocado.html  Different varieties are obviously different though: http://ucavo.ucr.edu/General/Ratios.html